Fields are not inline editable despite permissions
I want users to be able to inline edit some fields on the account record page. I have a permission set that grants edit access to these custom fields on the account object. On the page, the UI behavior for these fields is set to “None”. I have also granted object level edit access for the account object in this permission set.
I have granted this permission set to myself and other users but no one can edit the fields. They have edit permission, and the flexipage has UI behavior of “none”. There is no pencil icon that will allow the users to inline edit. Is this is an existing Salesforce bug?

Are you sure they can edit the record? Are they able to edit the field under edit as compared to inline?
